# php & mySQL: Selecting Multiple Books and showing their info in next screen

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

Let me illustrate this with an example.

1. Consider there are 10 books (there may be more, even 100+ on a single screen). A customer can order any number of books. In the fontend, each book is represented in a row and the book details are arranged column wise. Now the 10 books (along with their details) are shown in 10 rows.

   ```
   BOOK_NAME   DESCRIPTION   PRICE 
   B1          Book 1      10      Checkbox
   B2          Book 2      20      Checkbox
   B3          Book 3      30      Checkbox
   B4          Book 4      40      Checkbox
   ...
   B10           Book 10     100     Checkbox
   ------------------------------------------
   Add to Cart button
   ```
2. Now, a user can check any number of books above. When 'Add to Cart' button is clicked, I would like the next screen to show the details of the selected books in the above format. So for example, if the user selects: B1, B3 and B10 and clicks 'Add to Cart' button, in the next screen, I want to show it as below:

   ```
   BOOK_NAME DESCRIPTION    PRICE  IN_STOCK
   B1          Book 1      10          2 
   B3          Book 3      30          5
   B10           Book 10     100         1
   ```

I have added the 'In stock' column. In this column, the number of each of the books (in stock) is shown.

I  am having trouble with my current query doing the above, so would really helpful if anyone can help me with this. I have indicated the parts where I am experiencing the most trouble by placing ????? there. I am trying to do this in the most efficient way and in a single query without having to perform the query over and over (in a loop). (Please note that in case 50 books were checked, then the 50 rows of books with their relevant info needs to be shown. So hopefully that makes sense.)

**My current query:**

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books_stock WHERE books_stock.book_id ????? ) AS  books_in_stock,
                books.book_id, books.description, books.book_price, books.book_name
                FROM books 
                INNER JOIN books_stock  ON books.book_id = books_stock.book_id
                WHERE book_id ?????
```

I believe once the query is done, I would need to do a

`while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result) )`

in order to be able to show the results. Am I right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books_stock WHERE books_stock.book_id = books.book_id ) AS  books_in_stock,
            books.book_id, books.description, books.book_price, books.book_name
            FROM books 
            INNER JOIN books_stock  ON books.book_id = books_stock.book_id
            WHERE book_id IN (21, 23, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a long time since I used MySQL, but in oracle you could replace your ???? with

```
IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

where 1,2,3,4,5 is a comma-separated list of your book ids.

I'm pretty sure that would work in MySQL as well.